# What is the definition of "ples"

Tags: modeling

What does *ples* mean? The editors section, on the picture attached, has an arrow that points to the word *ples*. I would like to know what it means. [image]

Comment: I guess that is pies (pie menus), but it would have helped to know WHERE you took that image, isn't it?

Comment: @m.ardito it comes from https://www.blender.org/manual/interface/introduction.html#screen-elements and that image should be fixed so it doesn't like like pLes :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a problem with the typographic choices of the person who wrote that manual page. it doesn't say `ples` it says `pies`

Comment: i'll be reporting this to the guy(s) in charge @Daniel, thanks for the question.

Answer (score 0):

in the meantime: does this diagram help?

[image]